# How to revision Task defination in AWS with respect to existing task definition using AWS Cli

Tags: shell, amazon-web-services, docker, aws-ecs

I m trying to change some parameters in a Task definition in AWS(like CPU and Memory). I can do that process directly in Aws account by revisioning the Task definition and editing the parameters through JSON. But now I m trying to automate my process with AWS cli but I m able to register a new task definition but not able to revision the existing Task definition. All I want to do is create a new Task definition with provided task definitions config and minor changes to it using AWS CLI.

Answer (score 0):

you can't modify existing task definition revision, you have to create new revision each time.

Comment: I was looking for how to do a revision using "AWS CLI".